# Coincidence? : $d(ax^2+bx+c)/dx=\pm \sqrt{\Delta}$

Tags: polynomials, derivatives, roots, quadratics

As the title says, is it just a coincidence that $d(ax^2+bx+c)/dx=\pm \sqrt{\Delta}$? (where $\Delta=b^2-4ac$, i.e. discriminant of the quadratic). We can get this easily from rearranging the quadratic formula:

$$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$\iff 2ax+b=\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$

$$\iff \frac{d(ax^2+bx+c)}{dx}=\pm \sqrt{\Delta}$$

but that doesn't explain *why* it's true, i.e. why the derivative of a quadratic equals $\pm$ square root of $\Delta$. Seems  a touch mysterious.

EDIT: I found this in a book entitled "Vedic Mathematics" by Bharati.

Comment: It's not the derivative everywhere, the first equality only holds in the roots. So in fact, its the derivative evaluated in the roots.

Comment: Sometimes math works out to be neat.

Comment: as a consequence  the graph of $f$ has opposites slopes at the intersections with the horizontal axis.

Comment: Well, at one root it's $-\sqrt{\Delta}\leq 0$ and at the other root it's $0\leq\sqrt{\Delta}$ (if it has real roots). At the moment I don't see why this should be this way, let's see if someone has an answer. And yes, you could define the discriminant as the derivative evaluated in any of the roots squared.

Comment: @EulerianAdventurer Oh I'm afraid I cannot. I'm just as interested as you in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing the function with its roots seems helpful. The derivative can be written with terms like $x_1-x_2$ which its product is related to the discriminant.

Let the roots of $f_2(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$ be $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then $f_2(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ and $\Delta=(a(x_1-x_2))^2$. Differentiation gives $f'_2(x_1)=a(x_1-x_2)=\sqrt{\Delta}$.

Looking at the cubic function, $f_3(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$, we have $f'_3(x_1)=a(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)$. And $\Delta=a^4((x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)(x_3-x_1))^2$. So similar result does not hold because $(x_2-x_3)$ is missing. But their product $f'_3(x_1)f'_3(x_2)f'_3(x_3)=\Delta/a$ and in this way, the equation can be generalized to order $n$ polynomials as $$\prod_{k=1}^nf'(x_k)=\left(\frac{\Delta}{a^{n-2}}\right)^{(n-1)/2}$$